# Can't install .deb files on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 17.04

I just tried an install of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 (looks really nice) and have been able to install from command line and Software Install.

However, if I download a `.deb` file, eg virtualbox or atom editor, the .deb opens in software install, I click Install but nothing happens, not even a flicker. (did not have this issue on 16.04 or 16.10)

> Is there a know problem? Is there an alternative way to install a downloaded `.deb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem too (I was trying to install logmein hamachi), you should install [gdebi package manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/).  It worked to install debs on my machine.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I read elsewhere that worked but in the mean time found the solution posted below.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [in this post on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt%20%20here)

The post has 3 solutions. I used this one:

> You can install it using
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file followed by sudo apt-get install -f
> ```

Atom launched and is installed

Comment: You can (and should) accept you own answer (unless there is a better one, of course )

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by logging out, then logging back in under Ubuntu Xorg.  After that I was able to install gdebi and synaptic and successfully install programs as expected.

In particular, I downloaded the chrome deb file, opened it with gdebi and had no problems.